# How to safely store JWT using React App

Tags: authentication

Currently I'm working on a React-Laravel stack application. Having already built an SPA using React and a backend in Laravel, the plan is to use the backend as a REST API to make requests from the frontend.

I am using JSON Web Tokens with Laravel Passport in order to achieve authentication. However, storing the auth token in a secure way cannot be done, as both localStorage and cookies are not secure.

My question is this: What alternative route can I take to secure my app (where its security is paramount), having already built out a fair bit of the frontend and backend?

Comment: Related: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid

Comment: Could you explain why you consider local storage and cookies insecure?

Comment: Both of which can be tampered with on the frontend by malicious users, e.g. cross-site-scripting attacks.

Comment: Even when the cookies and the local storage is tampered. The attacker cannot set a valid value to there **without knowing your secret** that used to sign the JWT. They definitely are able to change the stored value. However, the new value will be an invalid one in 99.99% and will be ignored in Passport.

Comment: So there are no security liabilities in using Passport with a React app?